# Trying to center a page with images that bleed off the page on either side

Tags: html, css

I am an HTML/CSS novice and am trying to build a website for my wedding next year. On the main page [here](http://www.sarahandmike.ca) I have identical ribbon images on either side of my main div. What I want to happen is that the site remains centered no matter the screen resolution (showing more or less of the ribbons on either side depending on the resolution). It seems to work for the left ribbon but the right does not want to cooperate. The issue is particularly bad on iPads where the entire site appears left justified and the entire right ribbon is visible.

Any help would be welcome,

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

apply the following css to html:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

applying `overflow:hidden` to the img won't work, the img isn't overflowing relative to its own width. (in contrary to how you think the overflow property would work)

Comment: That worked perfectly for desktop browsers, but I still have a problem with iPads. The left ribbon is completely cut off and the right is shown completely.